# Admin side and user side website pages protection in next js 14

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I am using nextjs 14 - and i want to create website like property app where there will be admin dashboard & user side so how can i protect admin side and user side and how will be my folder structure

I know that there we can use middleware but how can i do that i want detail kindly

I tried to have two layout like one for auth , one for dashboard and one for user side now want to that if user is login then he had access to all pages related to user side and when admin is login he has the access to go to all pages of admin dashboard

but if no one is login then cant go to all pages but straightly goes to login page but i am unable to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't know how authentication and authorization works in `Next.js`, there is a [dashboard app](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app), which I suggest you read it. There is an [adding authentication](https://nextjs.org/learn/dashboard-app/adding-authentication) section which specifically talks about this.

But if you have a problem understanding the logic, I prepared some basics just to give you an idea about how to do what you asked,

```js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server';

export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const { pathname } = request.nextUrl;
  
  // Assuming you have a function to verify the user's role
  const userRole = getUserRole(request);

  // Define routes that require admin access
  const adminRoutes = ['/admin/dashboard', '/admin/settings'];
  // Define routes that require user access
  const userRoutes = ['/user/profile', '/user/settings'];

  // Redirect to login if not authenticated
  if (!userRole && pathname.startsWith('/admin/') || pathname.startsWith('/user/')) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/login', request.url));
  }

  // Redirect if user does not have admin access
  if (userRole !== 'admin' && adminRoutes.includes(pathname)) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url));
  }

  // Redirect if user does not have user access
  if (userRole !== 'user' && userRoutes.includes(pathname)) {
    return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url));
  }

  return NextResponse.next();
}

// Mock function to get user role from the request
function getUserRole(request: NextRequest): string | null {
  // Implement your logic to retrieve user role from cookies, JWT, etc.
  return null; // Placeholder return
}
```

You can search for `Role-Based Authorization` or `Role-Based Access Control` and you will find many examples.